# Error with geoJSON file for Mapbox

Tags: geojson, mapbox

I'm attempting to use MapBox to display multiple properties that are all clustered in a city.

(Haven't decided between this vs. Leaflet)

It's my first time dealing with geoJSON stuff, and attempting to create the file of the multiple addresses.

Here's a sample that I got from somewhere online, and Mapbox keeps saying this: `Error: Could not read dropped GeoJSON`

It's from this file called testing.geojson which only contains the following:

```
{
    "type": "MultiPoint",
    "coordinates": [
        [-105.01621, 39.57422],
        [-80.6665134, 35.0539943]
    ]
}
```

I'm really confused why it keeps generating that error, as I was hoping to make this sample work with actual addresses of the properties.

Any advice/help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

Just realized that I didn't make it clear that I was attempting to create a geoJSON list so I could import it into the MapBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GeoJSON in your question should be defined within the `geometry` attribute of your GeoJSON, like this:

```
{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": { 
        "type": "MultiPoint", 
        "coordinates": [
            [-105.01621, 39.57422], 
            [-80.6665134, 35.0539943]
        ]
    },
    "properties": {}       
}
```

Comment: hm, generates this error when I try to import it into MapBox: `Error: Could not read dropped GeoJSON: invalid JSON`

Comment: by the way, just realized that I didn't make it clear that I was trying to import the file into the MapBox. Mea culpa.

Comment: @user2730725 - sorry about that I should have [linted](http://geojsonlint.com/) it first.  it should be valid now.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Quick question that you don't have to answer but is there any way to attach additional information for each coordinate so that way you don't have to figure out which property is which so you can name it, and possibly add additional information by hand which is super time consuming. Also, what is the difference between multipoint and featurecollection, if you know?

Comment: I'm not completely sure about this...but...I think that if you want to have uniquely identifiable information about each specific point, you will want to create many `Point` features, rather than a single `MultiPoint` feature.

Comment: Also, information such as `name`, and other properties can be defined within the `properties` attribute

Comment: As to the `MultiPoint` and `FeatureCollection` distinction, `MultiPoint` is a `geometry` type that can contain many point coordinates, while a `FeatureCollection` is a `feature` type that can contain many features (such as points, polygons (and multipoints))

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in our normalization of GeoJSON - it was handling other types and turning them into FeatureCollections, but I had missed this case. Just fixed it now, should no longer be a bug!